Where in VSCode can I change the minimum version for the plugin cloud_firestore?
I'm getting the following error when building a flutter app for MacOS:

The pod "Firebase/CoreOnly" required by the plugin "cloud_firestore"
requires a higher minimum macOS deployment version than the plugin's
reported minimum version.

Where in VSCode can I change the minimum version for the plugin cloud_firestore?
The logfile says:
In Podfile:
        cloud_firestore (from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/macos`) was resolved to 5.4.4, which depends on
          Firebase/CoreOnly (~> 11.2.0)

If I download an older version of cloud_firestore from here:

https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/versions

would it be compatible with the rest of the firebase install?  And how do I swap out the cloud_firestore file?
